# having Can't mass-assign protected attributes: when there is attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In User.rb

```
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :prints, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  before_create :build_profile

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes
```

Is there any problem with arrangements?

Edit 1:

Error is: "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: profile"

Edit 2:

my profile.rb model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :phone
  belongs_to :user

end
```

and my form:

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'E-mail Address' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Password Confirmation' %>

  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>

  <%= profile_form.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Name' %>
  <%= profile_form.text_field :address, :placeholder => 'Address' %>
  <%= profile_form.phone_field :phone, :placeholder => 'Phone (example: 0193284647)' %>

 <% end %>

 <p><%= f.submit "Sign up", :class=>'btn btn-primary' %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Solution (using @Matt's answer):

```
<%= profile_form.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Name' %>
<%= profile_form.text_field :address, :placeholder => 'Address' %>
<%= profile_form.phone_field :phone, :placeholder => 'Phone (example: 0193284647)'
```

so it will use the "accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should looks like following:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_profile
end
```

Remove the hook

```
before_create :build_profile
```

in your model - you must not initialize the profile in your create action, it must happens in the new action.

And change your form from this:

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```

Your attr_accessible seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If it's complaining about `profile` rather than `profile_attributes` then your form may not be set up correctly. Post your form code. It should be something like the following:

Controller:

```
@user = User.new
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @user do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :profile do |fields| %>
    <%= fields.text_area :about_you %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have tried as suggested to use @profile instead of :profile but i got this error:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class.

The controller is set with:

   @user = User.new
   @profile = @user.profile

Comment: Altered my answer for a new user object. Use an object for the user and a symbol for the fields_for

Comment: This is the original code that i used with "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: profile" error. :(

Comment: Post your create action and the params that get passed to it, are you doing something with the profile_attributes that come through? Converting them from profile_attributes to profile or something?

Answer (score 0):

It was my stupid mistake to use :profile instead of :profile_attributes.

@Matt - you are correct. 
@Mattherick - yeap. "before_create :build_profile" should be omitted in the model.

In fact i did not use the registrations controller override (for devise) which is odd, and it works perfectly.

Comment: If the answer that @Mattherick provided is correct (which it appears to be, at least to me), then you should consider accepting it.